# Pinax project does not load any static file in pythonanywhere server

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, pinax

I have a pinax account project working fine in my local environment and I want to deploy it to a serve. When I try it to do it, it happens the same problem as if I install the pinax account project in the pythonanywhere server, the website shows everything but it cannot access any static file.

```
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
]
```

Everything looks good, I follow the documentation, I run the `migrate`, `makemigrations` and `collectstatic` and I tried a lot of things but still I do not get it what is wrong. Might be bad installation of the pinax projects? I tried to do it manually and with `pinax-cli` as well
I also modified my WSGI:

```
path = '/home/manolodewiner/mysite'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

In my local environment it works perfect, so what could be the problem?

Comment: When it's running in debug mode locally, Django will serve static files for you.   But when it's in a production environment like PythonAnywhere, you need to configure something else to do that.  That's done in the "Static files" section of the "Web" tab.   Have you set up the routing there?

Comment: My god you safe my life. I lost a lot of time just because I did not see that. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @GilesThomas, could you please answer properly below? And `manolodewiner` could you please select his answer so he can get  reward points? Otherwise this question seems hasn't been answered. Thanks both. :)

Comment: Sure!  That's done.

Answer (score 1):

[copied from comment above]

When it's running in debug mode locally, Django will serve static files for you. But when it's in a production environment like PythonAnywhere, you need to configure something else to do that. That's done in the "Static files" section of the "Web" tab.